# Getting this error PLS-00311 the declaration is incomplete or malformed

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, types

I'm getting an error while compiling

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Test AS OBJECT (
  demo demo_tbl,
  demo2 demo2_tbl   
)
```

While i created demo2_tbl using

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "demo2_tbl"
```

Comment: That declaration of `demo2_tbl` seems incomplete. Is there more?

Comment: That's it. I'm new to plsql. can you help me how can i complete it

Comment: Depends what you want it to be. I can't guess. you can make it `as object` or `as record`, with some properties, similar to your type Test. Or it could be a `table of integer` or some other time. The possibilities are endless, and I don't know what you want to do.

Comment: and not just `demo2_tbl`. You need `demo_tbl` to be valid too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TL;DR] Don't use quoted identifiers unless you have a very good reason to; and even then, you probably don't want to use quoted identifiers.

---

> While i created demo2_tbl using
>
> ```sql
> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "demo2_tbl"
> ```

I'm assuming that your declaration of that type continued and it was something like:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "demo2_tbl" AS TABLE OF INT;
```

or

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "demo2_tbl" AS OBJECT( ... <rest of declaration here>
```

If you didn't and that was the complete statement then you have not fully declared the type; you have only done a forward declaration of the type so that it could be used as a `REF` (like a pointer) target.

If you didn't fully declare the type then that is what your problem is.

If you did fully declare the type then the problem is that you used a quoted identifier for `"demo2_tbl"` when you created it; so now you need to use a quoted identifier everywhere else when you reference it.

For example:

```sql
CREATE TYPE demo_tbl AS TABLE OF INT;
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "demo2_tbl" AS TABLE OF INT;
```

If you do:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Test AS OBJECT (
  demo demo_tbl,
  demo2 demo2_tbl   
)
```

Then you get the error:

> ```
> PLS-00201: identifier 'DEMO2_TBL' must be declared
> ```

But, if you use quotes:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Test AS OBJECT (
  demo  demo_tbl,
  demo2 "demo2_tbl"
)
```

It works.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=71da7bb7a93a4247b2067a5783710089)*

---

Now, the solution could be to use the quoted identifier everywhere... however, a **BETTER** solution is to fix the source of the problem and drop the badly named type and its dependencies (now, before you start using them) and recreate them with case-insensitively named ones:

```sql
DROP TYPE test;
DROP TYPE "demo2_tbl";
CREATE TYPE demo2_tbl AS ... etc. ...
CREATE TYPE Test AS OBJECT ... etc. ...
```

and then you don't need to remember to always quote it.